# To display values to dropdown menu php

Tags: php

I would like to display drop down list according to the database below. (bom table)

For example, when I choose 'Table' from the drop down list, it would display the bom_description, bom_quantity and UOM.

---

```
bom_id |bom_description |product_id |finish_product |bom_quantity |UOM
1        Table Tops        1            Table             1        /PC
2        Table Legs        2            Chair             4        /PC
3        Chair Seat        3                              1        /PC
4        Chair Back        4                              1        /PC
5        Chair Legs        5                              4        /PC
```

---

Select Product: Table (A drop down list)

(HTML table will display these)

```
bom_description |bom_quantity |UOM
Table Tops        1             /PC
Table Legs        4             /PC
```

When I click on Chair, it will show this

Select Product: Chair (A drop down list)

```
bom_description |bom_quantity |UOM
Chair Seat        1             /PC
Chair Back        1             /PC
Chair Legs        4             /PC
```

Right now, this is my code but the html table to display the content are not appearing.

```
        <script src="script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".itemTypes").change(function () {
                    if (this.value == 0) {
                        $("tr").show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $("tr").hide();
                        $(".header").show();
                        $("." + this.value).show();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

    <?php
        session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header('location: homepage.php');
    }

    //connect to database
    include ("dbFunctions.php");

    $queryBOM = "SELECT * FROM bom";

    $resultBOM = mysqli_query($link, $queryBOM) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    mysqli_close($link);
    ?>

Select Product:
                            <select class="itemTypes">
                                <option value="0">
                                    all types
                                </option>
                                <?php
                                while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultBOM)) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row1['finish_product']; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $row1['finish_product']; ?>
                                    </option>
                                <?php } ?></select>
                            <p>


                                <table border="1">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>BOM Description</th>
                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                        <th>UOM</th>
                                        <th colspan="2">Action</th>

                                        <?php
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultBOM)) {
                                            $bom_description = $row['bom_description'];
                                            $bom_quantity = $row['bom_quantity'];
                                            $UOM = $row['UOM'];
                                            ?>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td><center><?php echo $bom_description; ?></center></td>
                                                <td><center><?php echo $bom_quantity; ?></center></td>
                                                <td><center><?php echo $UOM; ?></center></td>
                                                <td><center>
                                                        <form method="post" action="editBOM.php">
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="bomID" value="<?php echo $bom_id; ?>" />
                                                            <input type="image" src="images/editicon.png" name="edit" value="edit" style="width:30px;height:30px;"/>
                                                    </center></form>
                                                </td>
                                                <td><center>
                                                        <form method="post" action="dodeleteBOM.php">
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="bomID" value="<?php echo $bom_id; ?>" />
                                                            <input type="image" src="images/deleteicon.png" name="delete" value="delete" style="width:25px;height:25px;"/>
                                                    </center></form>
                                                    </center></td>
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </tr>
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

My initial answer was wrong.
You need to reset the point where you read the results between the two loops.

Put this after you finish creating the select element

```
<?php mysqli_data_seek($resultBOM, 0); ?>
```

if it is not showing the selectbox content either. Then move the following to the end of the file (Between  ofcourse:

```
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried but the content are not displaying still

Comment: Is the select being filled ?